# what is the best method to return db query and additional information from other methods

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and trying to continue to learn base on best practices.
I am trying to return data from multiple sources -- one source being a mysql db query and another source from another method that will pull data from facebook.

Here is what I have so far:

Model:

```
function get_users() {
  $this->db->select('id');
  $this->db->from('users');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->results;
}
function attach_cover($user_list) {
  foreach($user_list as $user){
    $user->cover = get_cover_value($user->id);
  }
  return $user_list;
}
```

controller:

```
$this->load->model('user_model', '', TRUE);
$data['users'] = $this->user_model->get_users();
$data['user_cover'] = $this->user_model->attach_cover($data['users']);
$this->load->view('index', $data);
```

view:

```
foreach($data as $item) {
  echo $item->id;
  echo $item->cover;
}
```

**Question**:

Is this the right approach to do so? Or is there a better method?

Comment: Probably a better question for [Programmer's Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). (Make sure to read their rules for what is on-topic etc)

Comment: I would suggest watch some of php academy tutorials on codeigniter MVC https://www.youtube.com/user/phpacademy/search?query=codeigniter even though out dated it gives you idea best methods. Codeigniter 2.2.1 latest but codeigniter 3.0 due to be released beta version I think soon

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct way to use codedIgniter.

As long as you don't put any logic in your views, never use any database related logic anywhere but a model and use the controller purely to combine the models and the views... you shouldn't be able to go too wrong.

CodeIgniter is not a very strict framework and it is unfortunately too easy to start putting things in the wrong places i.e. sql in the controllers.